# "Prerendered Icon Flag: true" in submitted iPhone app binary details, but icon shown with glossy effect in store

Tags: iphone, icons

"Icon already includes gloss effects" is set to YES in plist file. It worked for iPhone app 1.0 version. The same plist file without any modifications, 1.1 version is submitted for revision and got it approved. But the icon is shown in store with glossy effect. Checked the plist filename in target and is referring to correct file. Opened plist file in textedit and can see uiprerenderedIcon as true. Version 1.2 binary uploaded again and I can now see prerendered icon set to true in binary details, but the app icon in app details page is still shown with gloss effect.

What am I missing here? I am using Xcode 4.0.2 version and 4.3 SDK.

Comment: Is there a checkbox for this in iTunes Connect nowadays?

Comment: I didnt find any checkbox. version 1.0 is submitted barely 12 days back and 1.1 submitted 5 days back. i didnt find any difference in itunesconnect.

Comment: I'm experienced the same. Just wait to see what happen when my 1.1 is approved

Comment: There are few apps which are updated in store on Aug 23(yesterday) & Aug 24(today) and those icons didnt have gloss effect. My app 1.1 is updated into store yesterday i.e. 23rd Aug.

Comment: Same here. Will try it out tomorrow using an older xcode.

Comment: @lupu1001 how did it go? I'm curious to know if the bug is just within iTunes Connect or if it also affects the App Store?

Comment: one of my other app also updated into store yesterday Aug 30. prerendered flag didnt work for this app also. Looks like this issue is not yet resolved.

Comment: Closing since the issue as a bug on Apple's side and they have fixed it.

Comment: I've seen it happen other times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted iTunes Connect after seeing the same issue and got the following response six days ago. But it still isn't fixed and I haven't heard back from them.

> On Sat, Aug 27, 2011 at 10:22 PM,  wrote: Re:
>   iTunes Connect
>
> Hello Sebastien,
>
> Thank you for reporting the error you are encountering on the App
>   Store with your applications Large Icon.
>
> Please know that we are aware of this issue and are currently
>   investigating it with case number 9657298.
>
> We will let you know once we have any updates or additional
>   information with regard to this issue. Please be sure to reference the
>   Case number listed above for any follow up emails. Thank you in
>   advance for your patience in this matter.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Randall Apple Developer Support

Comment: And as of today, I've noticed that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: And here's an email I just received:

Hello,

We are following up with you regarding the recent issue you've experienced on the App Store with your application's Large Icon.

Our systems teams have corrected the issue and your application's Large Icon should now appear as intended.

Thank you for your patience while we worked to correct the issue. Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

Best Regards,

Heather
Apple Developer Support

Comment: looks like everything has been fixed. So accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

They have a bug. I updated 3 of my apps between Aug 23 and now and for all of them the 512x512 icon has the glossy effect although I have set "Prerendered Icon Flag: true" for all. I had no problems with apps submitted a week before.

I did not change my XCode or anything else in the meantime so it's not developer related. I wrote to Apple and I'm waiting for an answer.

I also noticed that when I register a new app and upload the 512x512 icon this doesn't have the glossy effect although icons uploaded without the binary always had this effect. So maybe they updated their code and now they treat this variable as false when it's true and true when it's false.

Comment: please update this post once you had reply from apple.