# Can I change my iPhone Apps large icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, submission

I just got my iPhone game up in the app store, but I don't like the gloss effect on the large icon in the app store.  I have two questions:

1.) Is it possible to change your large icon without resubmitting a binary?  In iTunes Connect there is no upload files button under the large icon like there is for your screen shoots.

2.)  How do I remove the gloss effect on the large icon?  I have "Icon already includes gloss effects" already set to yes in my info.plist, this fixed the installed icon but not the large icon.

Thanks in advance.

If you want to look at the icon:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cannonball-bounce/id481933077?mt=8

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but personally I wouldn't worry about it too much - it looks fine to me!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but on the iPhone I think the glare overpowers the icon.  It looks fine on the computer though.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at Apple Application Icons Guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

Comment: Thank, I have read this and I just read it again.  It doesn't really help me with the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, you can't! You need to resubmit the app.

2) You have changed correct preference. After resubmission it will take effect also in the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  For answer number two I have that setting set for the current submission, is there a reason why it didn't take effect?  It is nested under icon files->Icon already includes gloss effects, can the nesting be a problem?

Comment: A version with this preference is already published on App Store?

Comment: Yes, the one that is giving me troubles with it.

Comment: Then it looks like a bug in App Store and/or iTunes Connect. I suggest to contact Apple about this issue.

Comment: Yeah, your first answer was correct.  The 2nd way was too specific to my application.  My "Icon already includes gloss effects" setting was nested in a group called Icons (IOS5), so I took it out there and made it global to the whole info.plist and it worked!  If you look at  my link in the question, you can see that there is no more gloss effect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the size of icon. iPhone Application icon size is specified in Apple Developer Document

Answer (score 0):

Question 1. has already been answered, sadly it's no.

Question 2 is probably due to a bug on Apple's side, so if I were you I would ask them using the contact form in iTunes Connect. I did this for a similar bug that occurred in the past and it was eventually fixed by Apple without requiring re-uploading apps, see ["Prerendered Icon Flag: true" in submitted iPhone app binary details, but icon shown with glossy effect in store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172580/prerendered-icon-flag-true-in-submitted-iphone-app-binary-details-but-icon-s/7280952#7280952)